# Ninject with WCF again

Tags: ninject

There are a number of questions on SO that *look* similar, but none of what I've seen covers my scenario.

I am not using the WCF extension. This is how I register the WCF service with Ninject:

```
Bind<IPricingService>().ToMethod(Create).InSingletonScope();
```

Where `Create` method boils down to call to `RealProxy.GetTransparentProxy` provided by WCF.

Now this call returns, as you can imagine a transparent proxy, and when Ninject calls GetType on it in `Context.Resolve` method `null` is returned. Then, when activation plan is tried to be build an exception is thrown as Planner.GetPlan does not accept nulls.

Anyone knows what's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out that the issue was (like in many cases on SO) in the part that is not described in the question. Basically, call to `GetType` gets routed via proxy too, which I should have guessed. On the way it comes via `ClientBase.Invoke` override, where the method to call is searched on the 'ClientBase.Channel' (this is standard WCF type). Naturally this method is NOT found on channel, since it only implements interface methods. Thus I'm getting null. Not an Ninject issue - my own.